# Use RecyclerView inside a ViewPager

Tags: android

I implemented a ViewPager with 3 fragments A, B and C. So it works I can switch fragment with a slide effect. But now I want implement a RecyclerView in each fragment.

I have this error :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.computeHorizontalScrollRange(RecyclerView.java:1153)
            at android.view.View.onDrawScrollBars(View.java:11972)
            at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14471)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.draw(RecyclerView.java:2440)
            at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13362)
            at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13404)
            at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14182)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3103)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2940)
            at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13357)
            at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13404)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3077)
            at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13300)
            at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13404)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3077)
            at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13300)
            at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13404)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3077)
            at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13300)
            at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13404)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3077)
            at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13300)
            at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13404)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3077)
            at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13300)
            at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13404)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3077)
            at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13300)
            at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13404)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3077)
            at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13300)
            at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13404)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3077)
            at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13300)
            at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13404)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3077)
            at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13300)
            at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13404)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3077)
            at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13300)
            at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13404)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3077)
            at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13300)
            at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13404)
            at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.buildDisplayList(HardwareRenderer.java:1570)
            at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.draw(HardwareRenderer.java:1449)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2377)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2249)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1879)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:996)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5600)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My code for fragment A :

```
@EFragment(R.layout.test_bordeaux_a_view)
```

public class TestBordeauxAFragment extends Fragment{

```
@Bean
DirectionsAdapter mDirectionsAdapter;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test_bordeaux_a_view, container, false);

    RecyclerView mDirectionsRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.mDirectionsRecyclerView);
    mDirectionsRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mDirectionsRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManagerLM = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    mLayoutManagerLM.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL);
    mDirectionsRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManagerLM);
    //mDirectionsRecyclerView.setListener(this);
    mDirectionsRecyclerView.setAdapter(mDirectionsAdapter);

    //Use Retrofit to execute a request on my API
    RestProvider<CityService> bordeauxServiceRestProvider = new RestProvider<>();
    bordeauxServiceRestProvider.getService(CityService.class).getDirections(1, "A", new Callback<Result<Direction>>() {
        @Override
        public void success(Result<Direction> directionResult, Response response) {
            mDirectionsAdapter.addItems(directionResult.getCollection(), mDirectionsAdapter.getItemCount());
            mDirectionsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {

        }
    });

    return rootView;
}
```

}

Thank you for your help

Comment: where you instantiate mDirectionsAdapter class?

Comment: Guess he is using Android Annotations so the bean is created for him.
Have you tried to move the code in `onCreateView` in the @AfterViews method ?
Moreover, you need to retrieve your UI elements with the @ViewById annotation.

Comment: Yes Quentin I use AndroidAnnotations and I tried to use the method AfterViews but she's never called probably because of my ViewPager.

Comment: I don't know why my method AfterViews is never called, anybody knows ?